# Power BI Embedded - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We are using Power BI Embedded and reports are loading in the application, but on the console side it's giving this error:

> https://wabi-paas-1-scus-redirect.analysis.windows.net/explore/explorations/767626/cache 401 (Unauthorized)

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"data":"","status":401,"activityId":"xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-07e059c30510","requestId":"xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4cff3f5bf2a0","responseRequestId":null,"pendingRequestCount":0}reportEmbed.min.js:1
    at I (reportEmbed.min.js:1)
    at t.rejectInternal (reportEmbed.min.js:1)
    at t.reject (reportEmbed.min.js:1)
    at reportEmbed.min.js:1
    at reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:800
    at m.$digest (reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js:811)
    at reportEmbed.min.js:1
    at t.invoke (reportEmbed.min.js:1)
    at Object.onInvoke (reportEmbed.min.js:1)
    at t.invoke (reportEmbed.min.js:1)
```

We have 22 days left for Pro trial so I think the problem is not about Pro license for now.

On the Azure Active Directory for Power BI service permissions of application, I didn't confirm these options:

- Read and write all content in tenant
- View all content in tenant

Can it be reason of the issue? Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?

Edit : 
I asked a question here to : https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/401-Unauthorized-Power-BI-Embedded/idc-p/642572#M40273

Comment: We're facing this as well--and we have pro.  This just started erroring for us within the past couple of weeks.  We used to not get the error.  It seems to impact the "render" event getting fired consistently.

Comment: @CamHart Did you got any help from power bi community to fix this issue ? Did you fix ?

Comment: We setup our Development environment months ago and are not getting this in Dev. We just setup  Production creating a new App Registration with identical permissions but in Production we are getting this 401 error on the /cache/ call. Have not found a solution yet.

Comment: @GülayKülekçi No, they're worthless...

Comment: Thanks for informations  .

Answer (score 0):

I have the same errors occurring in my power bi embeded reports. I reported the issue to Microsoft and it was confirmed a bug. Its not slated to be fixed until October 2019 currently. Microsoft confirmed its safe to go to Production with these errors occurring. The priority may be raised if others report this issue as well. You can report the issue if you go here https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/support/, scroll all the way to the bottom and click "CREATE SUPPORT TICKET".

[image]

[image]